# ASP.NET - Lazy Load - load dymanic text only when div is shown

Tags: c#, asp.net, lazy-loading

I want the ability to show text from the database, but only when the div is shown.  Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to go with here, but it's certainly possible.

One obvious way if you can use JQuery is:

```
if ( $("#someDiv").is(":visible") ){
   //show text from database
}
```

Another server side approach (asp.net web forms) is to make the `div` `runat="server"` and check the visibility property.

```
<div id="someDiv" runat="server"></div>

if(someDiv.Visible == true)
{
  //show text
}
```